# Extract content from the formula in a referenced cell in Excel 2007

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a cell A3 that says `Name`.

Cell F16 contains `=A3`, which displays `Name`, just like I want it to.

I need cell F26 to take the information from cell F16 and display the referenced location. In other words, I need F26 to display `A3`, taking it from F16.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was informed by fixer 1234 that my solution was only introduced in `EXCEL 2013`, so it will not work for you issue in `Excel 2007`

I am going to leave my previous answer up however, as it would be a solution to someone searching for how to do this with Excel 2013 or later.

This should work for you:

```
=MID(FORMULATEXT(F16),2,10)
```

Result: `A3` as text.

The `10` in the formula is just an arbitrarily large integer so that it will return everything after the equals sign that `=MID()` is skipping over.

Comment: This function was introduced in Excel 2013.  It isn't available in Excel 2007.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't believe this was only implemented in 2013. I remember doing this often... but maybe I was doing it in VBA and that is how I accessed the cell formula or I toggled the formula view and did copy paste value. I tried with all of the older functions, and can't come up with any that works compatibly. I guess you could just do trace precedents, but that doesn't get the value into the cell.

Comment: Maybe a VBA solution?  3rd party add-on?  LibreOffice Calc is free and includes the equivalent function: FORMULA().